# How can I delete a row from a Table in SAPUI5 Application when I used Model as XMLModel?

Tags: sapui5

I have created  SAPUI5 application, in that I have loaded  data from external .xml file  into a table, it was fine. Now, I am trying  to delete a specific row from that table.
For this purpose, I use this code:

```js
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();
oModel.loadData("Deployments.xml", "", false);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
oTable.bindRows("/service");   // here "service"  is the root element of xml file
    var oTable = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
    text: "Delete Service",
    press: function() {
        var idx = oTable.getSelectedIndex();
        if (idx !== -1) {
            var m = oTable.getModel();
            var data = m.getData();
            var removed = data.splice(idx, 1); // error showing at this line
            m.setData(data);
            sap.m.MessageToast.show(JSON.stringify(removed[0]) + 'is removed');

        } else {
            sap.m.MessageToast.show('Please select a row');
        }
    }
});
```

But, I am getting error at the line: `var removed = data.splice(idx, 1);`. However, the same code is good for when model is JSON. How can I delete a specific row from a table when model XMLModel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button to remove row from SAPUI5 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521618/button-to-remove-row-from-sapui5-table)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

var data = m.getData();

data is not an Array. It is a XML document.

To remove an entry from the document:

```js
var root = data.childNodes[0];
var aEntry = root.getElementsByTagName("entry");
root.removeChild(aEntry[idx]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a lot easier an more reliable to use a Bindings `BindingPath` to manipulate data belonging to a particular binding. Here is your adapted sample for a XMLModel:

```
press: function() {
    var iIdx = oTable.getSelectedIndex();
    var sPath = oTable.getContextByIndex(iIdx).getPath();
    var oObj = oTable.getModel().getObject(sPath);
    oObj.remove();
    oTable.getModel().refresh();
}
```

This way you save the hazzle of dealing with the XML structure and furthermore this will scale with any change in the binding path you might introduce in the future.

BR
Chris

Comment: Hello Chris,

 Thank you so much, 
Here I am using model as XMLModel,table which data is coming from XMLModel.I need to delete the row(which I select to delete)  from table as well as  XMLModel also. Please help me how to do this.

Thanks and Regards,
Nag.

Comment: the code above is doing exactly this?! What are you missing?

Comment: Hi Chris,

When I apply the above code which you gave , the row is deleted from table only, not from XMLModel. I want to delete from XMl document also. For example, suppose the  table have 3 rows which is made with this XML, if i delete any one row from table, the same row need to remove from  xml also.

Thanks.